# integral of a function with exponent

Tags: integration, exponentiation, binomial-theorem

Can anybody help me to solve the following integral?

$\int_{0}^{\infty}(1-(ax+1)^{(1-y)} e^{-\frac{x}{b}})^M  dx$

It confuses me, because there is this Mth power of overall function.

Do I need to use substitution on (ax+1) or somewhere else?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: No indication about $a,b,y,M$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I only know that y and M are positive integers.

Comment: If  **y** and **M** are positive integers then  the integral is divergent.

Comment: Maybe try  binomial theorem with $(1+f(x,y,a,b))^M$ and interchange the sum?

Comment: Does it help to use Bernoulli's inequality to simplify or approximate the integral?